# Laravel multiple relation in a same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my project, users can like & comment on feeds & forums. So, there is a contribution page where the user can see where he has provided his input (like or comment) sorted by `created_at` time.

There may be another feature in future like feed & forum where user can also provide like & comment.

In my contribution page, I want to list data like this -

- You have commented on **`user_2`**'s feed **`feed_title`** at **`created_at`** - **`comment`**
- You have liked **`user_2`**'s feed **`feed_title`** at **`created_at`**
- You have commented on **`user_3`**'s forum **`forum_title`** at **`created_at`** - **`comment`**
- You have liked **`user_3`**'s forum **`forum_title`** at **`created_at`**

But I am stuck in `database` design. So far I am trying this -

```
Schema::create('contributions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->uuid('user_id');
            $table->uuid('contribution_id'); // id of my like/comment
            $table->string('contribution_type'); // feed_like/feed_comment/forum_like/forum_comment
            $table->uuid('target_id'); // id of feed/forum where I provided comment or like
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

But it will cause a query loop when I retrieve the data. So, is there any better approach to what I am trying to get?

Comment: I think this relationship is wrong. The user provides the contribution and the contribution is linked to something else. Therefore this is not a true ternary relationship. You'd need models: users, contributions, targets (e.g. forum, feed etc)  and pivot tables: user_contribution. The contribution is going to be 1-many polymorphic with the target. This will eliminate the need for the ternary relationship which is also unsupported in eloquent. @repox has provided the solution for the `contribution-<target>` side of this relationship but you still need to rework your database structure

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

That enables you to simplify the relationship by providing an ID of the related model and a naming of the related model instead.

A sample migration would look like this, using the [morph](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-morphs) method as inspiration (since you're using UUID's):

```php
Schema::create('contributions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->uuid('user_id');
            $table->uuid('contributable_id');
            $table->string('contributable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

This should enable you to do something like:

```php
class Contribution extends Model {

    public function contributable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}



class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's contributions.
     */
    public function contributions()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Contribution::class, 'contributable');
    }
}
```

You should be able to retrieve the users contributions that way and defining the action based on the morphed instance type.

Comment: Here if I save feed_like_id or feed_comment_id in the contributable_id field, is there any way to eager load the feed? The feed_id will be there in the feed_comment or feed_like table.